# how to create C# code for below XAML code?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have done below code in XAML. But, I dont wanna create Text Binding in XAML.  Is there anyway to create the same method in C# programmatically ?

XAML CODE:

```
<TextBox Name="contentBox"  Text="{Binding Content, Mode=TwoWay}" AcceptsReturn="True" />
```

Comment: Give in the details about the binding context. It might have changed away what you have done initially right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will look something like this:

```
        var tb = new TextBox();
        tb.SetValue(NameProperty, "contentBox");
        tb.AcceptsReturn = true;
        var b = new Binding("Content");
        b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        b.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(tb, TextBox.TextProperty, b);
```

You will still need to implement an `INotifyPropertyChanged` class for your `DataContext`, and manually insert the code-created TextBox into your visual tree somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.Name = "contentBox";
tb.AcceptsReturn = true;
Binding b = new Binding("Content");
b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
b.Source = this; // set you DataContext here
tb.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Content"); //Name of the property in Datacontext
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(contentBox,TextBox.TextProperty , binding);
```